# multiple tiles-def xml files

Tags: struts2, tiles2, apache-tiles

I'm using Struts 2.2.1 and tiles 2.1.4.

Wanted to know if there is a way to have multiple tiles-def xml files as my tiles-def xml file is becoming really big.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure but i believe you need to pass `param` to Tiles listener in `web.xml` something like

```
<context-param id="struts_tiles">
 <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
 <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/file1.xml,/WEB-INF/classes/file2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Code above is not tested :)